# Pylint warning typing final

Tags: python, pylint, pylintrc

I was using pylint --list-msgs and one of the warnings I got was this one:

- ``` :using-final-decorator-in-unsupported-version (W2602): *typing.final is not supported by all versions included in the py-version setting* Used when the py-version set by the user is lower than 3.8 and pylint encounters a ``typing.final`` decorator. ```
  I couldn't understand this warning because my version in .pylintrc and in the project is: 3.11, the only reference to typing in the project is this: `from typing import TypedDict`

I hope first is not receive this warning, because the project don't have reference with this warning, and if possible, understand the reason for the warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you launch `pylint --list-msgs` pylint is displaying a list of all its messages, it's going to always be the same for everyone and is not related to your code. Here's the doc for this message if you want more detail about it : https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/using-final-decorator-in-unsupported-version.html